# Many-to-many relationships with custom table names on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, rails-migrations

I'm a beginner with Rails (just finished Hartl's tutorial) and I'm having trouble with some types of associations that seem a bit more complex than the ones I've been exposed to so far. I've been browsing on google and stackoverflow for a solution to my problem but although I found many relevant answers I still can't figure out how to solve my problem.

Basically what I'm trying to do is implement the following relationships:

[image: ER diagram]

After researching about it what I came up with was:

**Models**

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email …

  has_many :speak, :class_name => "Speaks"
  has_many :speaks, :through => :speak, :source => :language

  has_many :want_to_learn, :class_name => "WantsToLearn"
  has_many :wants_to_learn, :through => :want_to_learn, :source => :language
  …

end

# models/language.rb
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso_639_1_code, :name_en, :name_fr, :name_pt

  has_many :speak, :class_name => "Speaks"
  has_many :users_who_speak, :through => :speak, :source => :user

  has_many :want_to_learn, :class_name => "WantsToLearn"
  has_many :users_who_want_to_learn, :through => :wants_to_learn, :source => :user
end

# models/speaks.rb
class Speaks < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'speak'
  attr_accessible :level, :language
  references :user
  references :language
end

# models/wants_to_learn.rb
class WantsToLearn < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'want_to_learn'
  attr_accessible :language
  references :user
  references :language
end
```

**Migrations**

```
# db/migrate/20130210153328_create_speak.rb
class CreateSpeak < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :speak do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :language
      t.integer :level

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  add_index :speak, :user
  add_index :speak, :language
end

# db/migrate/20130210153342_create_want_to_learn.rb
class CreateWantToLearn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :want_to_learn do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :language

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  add_index :want_to_learn, :user
  add_index :want_to_learn, :language
end
```

When I do this and try to run `rake:db migrate`, I get the following error:

```
-- add_index(:speak, :user)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "speak" does not exist
: CREATE  INDEX "index_speak_on_user" ON "speak" ("user")
...
```

If I comment out the lines with `add_index` the migration runs successfully, but then I can't create a "speaks" relationship from a user. For example, if I run:

```
> john = User.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "john@doe.com"...)

> john.speaks.create!(level: '6', language: '139')
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `references' for #<Class:0x007ff14c1771a0>
```

I've tried to replace all "references" with "belongs_to" and several other things, many of which I don't even remember, but to no avail. This has raised several doubts in my head, such as:

• Is "references" really the same as "belongs_to"? Even in the context of models? I've seen "references" been used in migrations but never models.

• Am I using "class_name" correctly? I'm really not confident about it. This is just what made most sense after everything I read but I haven't seen any example of customization in an association like this.

• What is wrong with adding those indexes?

And well, I don't know what the etiquette here is but my final question is:

How do I do all this properly??

Thank you in advance!

------ **EDIT** ------

I replaced the keyword "references" with "belongs_to" everywhere. The migration error about the indexes are exactly the same. When I comment the index creation lines, run the migration, create a user and then try the command

```
> john.speaks.create!(level: 6, language: 139)
```

The error is:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: level, language
```

In spite of the line `attr_accessible :level, :language`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I finally managed to get everything working and I think it wouldn't be very constructive for the community to just abandon the question unanswered. My code works perfectly now and it includes additions I had to make in order to allow nested forms. Here's how it looks:

**Models**

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, ... ,
  :speaks_attributes, :wants_to_learn_attributes
  # These last two attributes are necessary for nested forms

  has_many :speaks, :class_name => "Speaks", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :speaks, :allow_destroy => true # this one too
  has_many :speaks_languages, :through => :speaks, :source => :language

  has_many :wants_to_learn, :class_name => "WantsToLearn", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wants_to_learn, :allow_destroy => true # and this one too
  has_many :wants_to_learn_languages, :through => :wants_to_learn, :source => :language
  .
  .
  .

end

# models/language.rb
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso_639_1_code, :name_en, :name_fr, :name_pt

  has_many :speak, :class_name => "Speaks"
  has_many :users_who_speak, :through => :speak, :source => :user

  has_many :want_to_learn, :class_name => "WantsToLearn"
  has_many :users_who_want_to_learn, :through => :want_to_learn, :source => :user
end

# models/speaks.rb
class Speaks < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'speak'
  attr_accessible :language, :language_id, :level
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end

# models/wants_to_learn.rb
class WantsToLearn < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'want_to_learn'
  attr_accessible :language, :language_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end
```

**Migrations**

```
# db/migrate/20130210153328_create_speak.rb
class CreateSpeak < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :speak, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :language
      t.integer :level

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :speak, :user_id
    add_index :speak, :language_id
  end
end


# db/migrate/20130210153342_create_want_to_learn.rb
class CreateWantToLearn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :want_to_learn, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :language

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :want_to_learn, :user_id
    add_index :want_to_learn, :language_id
  end
end
```

In the migrations I put the "add_index" lines INSIDE the "def change" block cause last time I was stupid and distractedly left it outside, and changed "user" and "language" to "user_id" and "language_id", respectively. That fixed it.

Now I can create a user `ariel`, and make him speak Portuguese and French by running:

```
> ariel.speaks.create!(language_id: 129, level: 6)
> ariel.speaks.create!(language_id: 50, level: 4)
```

Then I can get the entries associated with `ariel` in the "speak" table by running:

```
> ariel.speaks
=> [#<Speaks id: 1, user_id: 1, language_id: 129, level: 6, created_at: "2013-02-25 19:30:01", updated_at: "2013-02-25 19:30:01">, #<Speaks id: 4, user_id: 1, la
nguage_id: 50, level: 4, created_at: "2013-02-26 12:37:34", updated_at: "2013-02-26 12:37:34">]
```

And the entries in the "languages" table by running:

```
> ariel.speaks_languages
 => [#<Language id: 50, iso_639_1_code: "fr", name_en: "French", name_fr: "français\n", name_pt: nil>, #<Language id: 129, iso_639_1_code: "pt", name_en: "Portugu
ese", name_fr: "portugais\n", name_pt: nil>]
```

The procedure is analogous for the wants_to_learn association.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the references keyword in Rails, but I see it in migrations in the Rails Guide, but not in classes, so don't use it in classes.

Thus, it is different than belongs_to, since belongs_to is used in classes, and references is used in migrations.

It is also new to me that the migration would care about the association in the class when creating an index.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick answer. I changed all occurrences of "references" to "belongs_to". I edited the question adding the results of this change.